# Passing custom structure as argument causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Working on implemeting graphs for a CS class project I declared these two structures

```c
typedef struct person {
   char name[128];
   int age;
} Person;

typedef struct graph {

   int knots;
   int adjacencies[500][500];
   Person personList[500];
  
} Graph;

void insertPerson(Graph *g, Person p) {
   g->personList[knots] = p;
   (g->knots)++;
}

void writeAdjacencies(Graph g) {

  for(int i = 0; i < MAXDIM; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < MAXDIM; j++) {
     printf("%d ", g.adjacencies[i][j]);
    }
   printf("\n");
  }

}
```

Everything is fine except that when trying to create a menu function (reading inputs and then deciding whether to add new person or remove existing one, etc...) passing a graph pointer and then using it's pointed instance seems to be generating a segmentation fault.

```c
void checkInput(int input, Graph *g) {

  int temp;
  char tempName[128];


  if(input == 1 ) {

    printf("\n  Name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", tempName);
    printf("%s\n", tempName);

    Person p; 
    strcpy(p.name, tempName);

    /* takes graph pointer a person and just adds person to personList and increases knots
       it's working as intended
    */
    insertPerson(g, p); 

    /* Goes through each element in the matrix and prints it
       this is the one causing problems
    */
    writeAdjacencies(*g); 

  }
  
}
```

The code is working fine until the moment I pass `*g`as an argument - that is if I put the `writeAdjacencies(*g)` under a comment it does not cause any trouble.

I don't get what is the issue here? I feel as if I'm using pointers like I did so far throughout the year and it worked. Maybe I could be passing a null pointer? But I did inialize it in the main function I think.

main.c :

```c
Graph graph;

for(int i = 0; i < MAXDIM; i++) {
 for(int j = 0; j < MAXDIM; j++) {
     g.adjacencies[i][j] = 0;
    }
 }
    
g.knots = 0;

checkInput(0, &g);
```

Any help is welcomed!

EDIT: included both missing functions

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible example. Please [edit] your question, providing definitions for the two missing functions,

Comment: Your `main` function (so far as you have communicated it to us) references the variable `g` but doesn't declare it. Please provide a [mcve] (read that link if you haven't already done so -- it will make your experience on Stack Overflow much more pleasant).

Comment: Hadn't read it. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the potential buffer overflows from your `scanf` code, your `Graph` structure is way too large for the stack (containing 250,000 integers). Use dynamic memory allocation instead. E.g.:

```
typedef struct {
    int** adjacencies;
    int n;
} Graph;

void graph_init(Graph* g, int n) {
    g->n = n;
    g->adjacencies = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        g->adjacencies[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
}

void graph_free(Graph* g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g->n; ++i) {
        free(g->adjacencies[i]);
    }
    free(g->adjacencies);
    g->n = 0;
}
```

Comment: For simplicity's sake the professor doesn't want us allocating memory that way. I took what you said anyway and just changing the dimensions from 500x500 to 20 seems to have fixed it. What is it about those potential buffer overflows? I don't really understand what it means but I'll search about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Watisdis12 Check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). In your particular code, consider what would happen if a user would enter more than 127 characters during the `scanf` input.